# PDO, strange behavior when working with the method `bindValue`

Tags: php, pdo

I need to get some data from the remote MSSQL using by stored procedure and after that bind this value when I call the next stored procedure. The value is just a string. I write

`$statement->bindValue(':value', $value, \PDO::PARAM_STR);`

, but the value is set to null. I tried to to bind another value manually and all ok. What does it mean?

Comment: what does `var_dump($value);` say? just before the `bindValue()`

Comment: value is a reserved word in mysql. if you use it in your query you have to escape it. do you use it?

Comment: The word `value` I use just for example. Can it be depend on charset or the type of the result that returns the first stored procedure?

Comment: You should add more information to your question. The query itself and the full php code that builds and executes the query might be interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood later the problem was with MSSQL uniqueidentifier type which need to convert to string manually using by the function http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-guid-string.php. I hope it helps somebody.